# How to share code between two project in Visual studio

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio, bitbucket

I work with one project which have a **Client and Server** side, for developing i use Visual studio.

So problem is, in my web page i have **Header panel** which are the same for Client and Server side, and if i provide some changes at header, i need to do this 2 times.

My question is, some how it possible to create separate **Header view** for ex in Bitbucket, and just make some changes in repo, and this changes will updates in **Client and Server** automaticly, or i need to copy past all time.

I found many examples about **submodules** but i cant found working example for **VS** which will works with **JS,HTML,CSS**.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at the practice called 'monorepo' and put the 2 projects 'Client' and 'Server' in the same repository...

Comment: @Philippe it's no possible to do this, because it's must be separated